# Auto increment Base64 mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, performance, base64

Sup guys, we are trying to use a base64 as a unique stringID on the MySQL database. Is it possible in a way to auto-increment this? The only way I found right now is to check it with a query and try-and-error over and over again wat's a very slow, annoying process even with NodeJS.

Comment: Why not just use a `bigint`?

Comment: We don't want to make it countable. It would be visible in the URL header.

Comment: Use a uuid if you want something "random".

Comment: Is the goal obfuscation?  You want it to be auto-incrementable; but this makes it easy for hacking?  Please elaborate on the goal(s).  You cannot auto-inc a base64 without a lot of code.  If you are taking base64 of some integer, then that could be incremented -- but that is easily hacked.